# Are there any plans for merchandise for stack overflow?

Tags: discussion

Today I'm wearing my wonderful shirt.

[image]

Is there, or should there, or will there be official merchandise? 
I'm proud to be a nerd and wouldn't mind supporting the site by wearing wonderful nerdy shirts.

Comment: Cross site dups: [What happened to the Stack Exchange Store?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store) and [Why can't Stack Exchange re-open the store?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147343/why-cant-stack-exchange-re-open-the-store)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are already several questions like this on the meta of StackExchange:

- [Place to buy StackOverflow, SuperUser and ServerFault Merchandise, Schwag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18519/place-to-buy-stackoverflow-superuser-and-serverfault-merchandise-schwag)
- [Where can I buy the Stack Overflow t-shirt?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157776/where-can-i-buy-the-stack-overflow-t-shirt)
- [Merchandising, merchandising, merchandising!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68842/merchandising-merchandising-merchandising)

But apparently the store has been permanently closed. This answer has a reasonable explanation: [What happened to the Stack Exchange Store?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store/137580#137580).

> Unfortunately, it no longer exists. The short story is that it was just too much work for the amount of sales we had.
>
> The long story is, we have a lot of remote employees in different states. Our sales tax burden for selling tangible goods started to become an administration nightmare. We also couldn't justify the costs of either having someone at the office ship swag or paying a fulfillment house to do it for us (we were doing both). It also was complicated by the fact that a few months ago, a group of people defrauded us for a few thousand dollars in merchandise before we caught it.

Comment: Ahhh that's a shame.

Comment: But ... but ... coudn't that be outsourced?  There are companies that make + distribute swag for other companies...? This spoils the 10M party!!!

Comment: You can also plagiarize shirts. Just copy the logo and send to a t-shirt company to make it lulz